# Which is the field used to show the picklist beside the reminder in event object

Tags: visualforce, administration

From where does this picklist come from. couldnt find anything related on event fields to get these values?

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear the reminder is stored only as a Date Time and a Boolean. So what your seeing appears to be a specialisation of the UI not driven in the usual way from a picklist. I observed that it is also not visible on the Layout editor either. So in answer to your question, sadly I have to conclude there is no specific field for this dropdown, it is purely a UI aid.

What I found apone further investigation was this...

```
Select ReminderDateTime, IsReminderSet From Event
```

When the event starts at 11:00 with a 2hr reminder ...

[image]

[image]

Gives...

[image]

**Update:** You can actually update the ReminderDateTime field with any date/time you want, however the UI will round it to the nearest value in the drop down. Not sure in practice when the reminder will fire, but wanted to add this further observation.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.. I am creating a Vf page which is very similar to events standard page and i was trying to get reminder option into the page. These picklist values should be coming up from some place, wanted to see if i could use what is available in SFDC. Other alternative would be to add the items to the select options in the Vf page and display that.

Comment: Yes this looks like the answer to your question is no sadly. So yes hard coding looks like your only option here, not the behaviour I have just added around round (if you want to care about external edits to the reminder date that is). It is not uncommon for some of the Salesforce pages to not follow Custom Object rules and specialise the UI this way.

Comment: I assume by the same token as we have observed here that <apex:detail> does not show this field?

Comment: @Prady We can use custom settings to store these picklist values and display

Comment: apex:detail requires an id for the event. I wanted to have a option to create a new event @AndrewFawcett

Comment: @MohithKumar if it is going to hardcoding then it would be custom settings only